# Trouble adding CNAME record for WAF to a hostname that already has an A record

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, oracle

I have a domain (for instance, example.com) that points to certain IP direction (type A record), and DNS system is controlled by my organization. Now, a new web app has been published at news.example.com. As it is located on a cloud service provider, in order to maintain easy access, we requested a new A record on our managed DNS  that should be created to point the name news.example.com to the cloud provider-assigned IP address for the host.

after that, we wanted to deploy a WAF in front of the news.example.com website to protect it. The Cloud service provider requires that I create a new CNAME pointing news.example.com to the target string provided by the cloud provider so that traffic gets routed through the WAF first. However, the CNAME record creation process fails because it says `there already exists an A record associated`.

Example CNAME record:

```
origin (news.example.com) - this one has already an A record pointing to its IP address.
target: xxx.yyyy.zzz.www. (info provided by Cloud Service Provider)
Type: CNAME
```

How can approach this problem? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CNAME` record can't coexist with other record types, see [RFC 1912](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1912#section-2.4). The following zone data is **incorrect**:

```
@ORIGIN example.com.
www IN A 192.0.2.1
www IN CNAME ccc
```

As a consequence, it is impossible to add true `CNAME` record at the apex of the zone. This follows from the fact there always is the `SOA` record at the apex, and `CNAME` could not possibly be alone, therefore it is forbidden. (Also there must be at least one `NS` record, and this case is discussed in the RFC.)

Some cloud providers emulate this "`CNAME` at the apex" behaviour, but in fact they are doing this using programmatically generated zone, not actually using `CNAME`, at least, not at the apex.

If you want to add `CNAME`, you have to remove `A` record of the same name. There is no other way.